# Git push write access for deployment denied

Tags: git, gitolite, permissions

I have strange issue when try git push. Git clone and commit works fine.

> W access for my_project DENIED to
>   deploy_my_project_

My gitolite.conf

```
repo my_project   
R = deploy_my_project_111 
RW+ = my_name
```

I wonder why git push takes wrong user (deploy_project_111) with read access.

This error is float. Twice i had to change rsa key(rsa keys is unchangeble) and restart computer. 
May be my computer do something wrong.

Comment: I don't recognize that syntax: you should have one line with repo yourRepo, then a line with RW+ yourName

Comment: Sorry. Has been edited

Comment: And do you have a public key with 'my_name' as parameter in the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

Comment: Yes i have public key with 'my_name'

Comment: However, the error message don't deny access for your name. It denies it for `deploy_my_project_`. What is the full address URI you are using to push? Do you have a `$HOME/.config` file on your client (from where you are pushing)?